# CoreData - to many property set returns empty though it presents in DB file

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have simple DB scheme: [image]

I fetch "WPRChatBoardItem" objects collection this way:

```
- (NSArray*)getAllChatBoardItems
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([WPRChatBoardItem class])];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor
                          sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error)
        [WPRLogger printError:error where:DEBUG_PLACE];

    return array;
}
```

When I print one of the objects, I see all three "to-many" properties are in status "relationship fault": [image]

After accessing each of them, I see in log fetch requests but but they all return empty even though there are entries in DB file: [image]

[image]

- I tried to set **setReturnsObjectsAsFaults** to NO, but this did not help.
- I use only one context

Comment: There are entries in the table, but they have ZCHATSBOARD = NULL, ie they are not related to any WPRChatBoardItem.  There may be a problem with the code where you set the relationship.

Comment: OMG! Hours for nothing. Consider moving your comment to answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are entries in the table, but they have `ZCHATSBOARD = NULL`, ie they are not related to any `WPRChatBoardItem`. There may be a problem with the code where you set the relationship.

Comment: Thank you. I've missed that.